# Joomla 1.5 contact form captcha

Tags: joomla-1.5

I'm searching for a captcha solution that will integrate with Joomla 1.5's native contact form.

I've tried [this solution](https://code.google.com/p/joomla-recaptcha/) on Google Code, but it fails to work.

I can't find any current solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Joomla 1.5 is outdated and not longer actively maintained. Joomla community of developers is working Joomla 3.

*You are not going to find new extensions supporting the latest captchas*. You can only develop your own custom code for this version and try to keep it running.

**You should definitely migrate to a stable and safe release (3.3.x). 1.5.x - 2.5.x are not longer being maintained.**